# Redirect non-www to www in subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file in the http://www.mysite.com/test/ that I am trying to use to send anyone accessing http://mysite.com/test/ to http://www.mysite.com/test/ but it's no working, here's my code:

```
# Force Caching
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|pdf|flv|mp3)$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive on
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 14 days"
 Header set Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# Enable gzip compression
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
 AddType application/x-javascript .js
 AddType text/css .css
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/x-javascript text/x-component text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/javascript
 <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
 </IfModule>
</IfModule>


# Main Rewrite rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Always use www.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .htaccess file is in the `/test` directory. This is why the `/test/` prefix is removed in the `RewriteRule`'s request URL pattern `.*`. To redirect the request properly, you must change the substitution to

```
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, no redirect actually happens. Whenever I access http://mysite.com/test/ it just loads the site without the redirect.

Comment: @spyke01 It works in my test environment. Do you have some other rules in this or any other .htacces?

Comment: I've edited the post above with the full .htaccess. There may be a .htaccess file in the main directory but I have to wait for access.

Comment: @spyke01 The other directives are not rewrite related. So, there shouldn't be a problem with them. I temporarily moved the .htaccess to the root directory and even there it redirects from mysite.com to www.mysite.com. Sorry, can't help you then.

Comment: No problem, must be an issue on my server, it worked fine off the main directory but not in the subdirectory.